# R Programming Shortcut: Composite Key

Tags: r, unique

Can anyone tell me how you can query a data frame and get all possible combinations of unique variables:

```
############### Data1 - 2 columns - one PK
data1 <- data.frame(rep_len(1, length.out = 10))
data1$PK <- rep_len(1:10, length.out = 10)

names(data1) <- c('DupData', 'PK')
rownames(data1) <- NULL

rapply(data1,function(x)length(unique(x)), how = 'unlist')

length(unique(data1$PK))

############### Data2 - 3 columns - Two column composite PK
data2 <- data1
data2$PK <- rep_len(1:2, length.out = 10)
data2$PK2 <- rep_len(2:6, length.out = 10)
rapply(data2,function(x)length(unique(x)), how = 'unlist')

length(unique(data2$DupData))
length(unique(data2$PK))
length(unique(data2$PK2))
nrow(unique(data2[,c(1,2)], nmax = 3))
nrow(unique(data2[,c(1,3)], nmax = 3))
nrow(unique(data2[,c(2,3)], nmax = 3))

############### Data3 - 4 columns - Three column composite PK
data3 <- data1
data3$PK <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1)
data3$PK2 <- c(0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,0,0)
data3$PK3 <- c(1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1)
rapply(data3,function(x)length(unique(x)), how = 'unlist')

length(unique(data3$DupData))
length(unique(data3$PK))
length(unique(data3$PK2))
length(unique(data3$PK3))
nrow(unique(data3[,c(1,2)], nmax = 4))
nrow(unique(data3[,c(1,3)], nmax = 4))
nrow(unique(data3[,c(1,4)], nmax = 4))
nrow(unique(data3[,c(1:4)], nmax = 4))
nrow(unique(data3[,c(2,3)], nmax = 4))
nrow(unique(data3[,c(2,4)], nmax = 4))
nrow(unique(data3[,c(3,4)], nmax = 4))
nrow(unique(data3[,c(2:4)], max = 4))
```

Without doing a for loop, I am looking for an 'rapply', or something, that will give you every combination of unique columns in the data frame. In the example above, when the value returned is 10, that is what I am looking for.

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: see `?table`  (+15 chars to be accepted)

Comment: Are you looking for permutations/combinations? Perhaps `combn` is a start, or even `expand.grid`. Otherwise, please provide the actual output you are looking for (saying "every combination" and "10 is what I am looking for" does not make enough sense to me).

Comment: I don't know how much clearer to make the question. in database terminology, I am looking for a way to profile data and define the columns that are candidates for primary keys. A composite PK means you have two or more columns that create a unique instance of a row - or observation in R terminology. I asked the question before, and they asked for data - so I provided data. If you run the reproducible code above, you will see that a key is unique, or combination is unique, when the number of unique elements = the number of rows in that data frames.

Comment: Possibly there is no way of doing what I ask without looping through the columns.